# How to use loader while page rendering in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a loader.gif image with a flag variable to show and hide.

```
<div [hidden]="IsLoading" class="loadingDiv"></div>
```

In my html having 200 records without pagination(the requirement is not need pagination). So I felt the rendering time is taking some time(around 5-10 sec). so I have planed to use `loader`.

```
cutomLoad() {
        this.IsLoading = false;
        this.tyreAndRimList = this.temptyreAndRimList;  // here having 200 records.       
        this.IsLoading = true;
    }
```

May be some guy's misunderstood my abouve question .I have tried above code. The code run very quick so am unable to see the loader But the page rendering is taking more time(*I don't want set timeout for some seconds*). I decided to show a loader on starting time of page rendering and hide the loader while end of the page rendering . But I don't have any idea about this.

### EDIT

I don't want to do this in when I change the navigation. I have using observable in $http call. So I can easily use the loader. that's not a problem. the main problem is when I filter/sort the 200 records at this time the same 200 records will re-rendering. In this time I want use loader.

Comment: i guess [router resolver](http://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/guard) is the way to go about this

Comment: @RahulSingh . Sorry I can't open this link from my office. But am expecting any events for start and end rendering

Comment: just check for router resolve

Comment: Can you explain how `temptyreAndRimList` works? Does it use an observable? A promise? I guess it's some sort of a an async operation.

Comment: Here is the link to the docs on the router resolver that Rahul mentioned: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data

Comment: @Catalyst. `temptyreAndRimList` variable having 200 records. I have using filter from this variable. But when I clear the filter I just assign all values to the binding object `tyreAndRimList`.At this time the rendering takes time.

Comment: So are you basically saying that the rendering of the data binding is taking 5-10 seconds? Not the data retrieval? That seems odd. Maybe you can demonstrate with a Plunker so we can all better understand your issue?

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a Plunkr, because I try to understand what is your problem but I think I cannot get reproduction. I was expecting the UI to freeze for a second on `this.tyreAndRimList = this.temptyreAndRimList;`.  [**Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/nLFadGrDWgx3cML1QqdY?p=preview) is a playground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do decide to use a route resolver, then you can set up a loading image based on the routing events. Something like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
    pageTitle: string = 'Acme Product Management';
    loading: boolean = true;

    constructor(private router: Router) {

        router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: Event) => {
            this.checkRouterEvent(routerEvent);
        });
    }

    checkRouterEvent(routerEvent: Event): void {
        if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
            this.loading = true;
        }

        if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd ||
            routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel ||
            routerEvent instanceof NavigationError) {
            this.loading = false;
        }
    }
}
```

So when you route to your component the loading is set to true. As the data is loaded as part of the resolver the image will display. Then when the resolver data is complete, the route is complete and loading is set to false.

I have an example of route resolve here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing in the APM-Final folder.

Comment: fine! But I want to know when the navigation start event will fire? the loader will show when I use sorting and filtering from the 200 records?

Comment: Oh ... maybe Rahul and I misunderstood your requirements. If you need to load the data separate from a route then neither a route resolver nor the example above will work for you. Could you update your question with more information on your scenario? Are you re-getting the 200 records when changing the sorting and filtering?

Comment: Are you re-getting the 200 records when changing the sorting and filteringAre you re-getting the 200 records when changing the sorting and filtering. Yes.   Am using observable to in $http call. so I can use loader easily. But I want to filter/sorting with the 200 records. Then the same render will happen, at this time I want to use loader.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "loader", but I have some info on filtering here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/filtering-in-angular/

Comment: Loader means. `loader.gif` image

Answer (score 1):

I think no need to write this function as well.
If you might have seen how root component works in index.html e.g, `<app-root>loading...</app-root>` in this 'loading...' will automatically be removed once a component has been loaded. so you can use the same concept here. `<component-selector><img src="..gif path"/></component-selector>`.

Answer (score -1):

```
cutomLoad() {
        this.IsLoading = false;
        this.tyreAndRimList = this.temptyreAndRimList;  // here having 200 records.       

    }

this.cutomLoad().then((resp) => {
      this.IsLoading = true;
  },
  error => {
      console.log(error);
      alert(error);
  });
```

Comment: What you mean? am does not returning any response from `cutomLoad()` method. How you hope this answer will solve my problem?